# Can I get the error name in PHP file uploads?

Tags: php, file, upload

When you show the error, you get the number:

```
$_FILES["uploadedFile"]["error"];
```

But you can make a switch that can actually recognize that statement as a case named after its correspondent error. If the sentence returns the error 2, which is "UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE", if we have:

```
case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
echo "error: UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE";
break;
```

It will execute the case. So somehow PHP knows the name the error and not only its number. Writing a whole switch or exception handler extension doesn't seem to be the easiest way...

Comment: `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE` is a constant and writing the whole switch statement is the only way.

Comment: Well that's the only way out

Comment: This particular constant has the value `2`, but other constants in other contexts might use the same value. Therefor there is no direct, _two-sided_ relation between `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE` and `2`. You can check whether the value equals that of the constant - this is a tool to make your code more readable. The purpose of those constants is not to be used in (end user-facing) error messages, so if you explicitly want that, you’ll have to implement that part yourself.